# Condense multiple conditional statements into one switch in styled-components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am wanting to condense many pre-existing button CSS definitions into one style-component. I am finding positive results by expanding my definition with conditionals, however I am getting to the point where the definition is becoming rather large and would like to know if there is a way in which I can condense my definition with some sort of `switch` statement to abstract out the CSS into something that is returned?

**Use case:**
I have a custom `<Button>` component that takes a couple of props `theme` and `type`, so an example of my button will be:

```
<Button theme="primary" category="my-cat">Click me</Button>
```

The `theme` and `category` will take 2 different variables each, so nothing crazy to think about so far...

My definition so far has become bloated as such:

```
export const Button = styled.a`
    background: lightgrey;
    // ... More standard stuff

    ${props => (props.theme === 'one' || props.theme === 'two') && `
        // ... more CSS
    `}

    ${props => (props.theme === 'one' && props.category === 'cat1') && `
        // ... more CSS
    `}

    ${props => (props.theme === 'one' && props.category === 'cat2') && `
        // ... more CSS
    `}
`;
```

Would it be possible to do something such that I can pass my props to a function and return the addition CSS based on those props and the conditional operations? Something like:

```
function styleMyEl(props) {
    switch(props) {
        case (props.theme === 'one' || props.theme === 'two'):
            // return my additional css
        case ...
        default:
            return;
    }
}

export const Button = styled.a`
    background: lightgrey;
    // ... More standard stuff

    ${props => styleMyEl(props)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try returning `css` block:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

function styleMyEl(theme) {
  switch (theme) {
    case 'one':
      return css`
        background: black;
        color: pink;
      `;
    default:
      return css`
        background: pink;
        color: black;
      `;
  }
}

export const Button = styled.a`
  ${props => styleMyEl(props.theme)}
`;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Button theme="one">Button</Button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button>Button</Button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image]

[image: Edit async-field-ts9e2]

---

It's a common problem, you can check [`styled-map`](https://github.com/scf4/styled-map) library which tries to address this issue:

> With Styled Components alone, you'll often do something like this:

```
const Button = styled.button`
 color: ${props =>
   props.primary && '#0c0' ||
   props.warning && '#c00' ||
   props.info && '#0cc' ||
   '#ccc'
 };
 border: 2px solid ${props =>
   props.primary && '#0c0' ||
   props.warning && '#c00' ||
   props.info && '#0cc' ||
   '#ccc'
 };
 font-size: ${props =>
   props.small && '8px' ||
   props.medium && '18px' ||
   props.large && '32px' ||
   '16px'
 };
`;

<Button primary large>Submit</Button>
```

> Here's the same component using `styled-map`:

```
import styledMap from 'styled-map';

const buttonColor = styledMap`
  primary: #0c0;
  warning: #c00;
  info: #0cc;
  default: #ccc;
`;

const Button = styled.button`
  color: ${buttonColor};
  border: 2px solid ${buttonColor};
  font-size: ${styledMap`
    large: 32px;
    small: 8px;
    medium: 18px;
    default: 16px;
  `};
`;

<Button primary large>Submit</Button>
```

You should look for related [`styled-components` utilities](https://www.styled-components.com/ecosystem) or implement one yourself, more examples are [`styled-is`](https://github.com/yldio/styled-is), [`styled-by`](https://github.com/brunobertolini/styled-by)

Comment: Seems interesting, but I'm not sure whether it will make my life any easier in this specific case. I have many conditionals to account for, some will be nested :-/

Comment: Ah I like the look of that. I'm just thinking of how it could perhaps be expanded to accommodate multiple different props...

Answer (score 2):

Contrived example but recently I got into mixin and I think it helps me a lot with organising my styled-components code. You can use switch case inside styled-components this way.

Basically, styled-components used template strings, so whatever you return from your code will run as like you write them inside the styled-components.

**Define the mixin**:

```
const mixin = props => {
  switch (true) {
    case props.p1 === "black" && props.p2 === 3:
      return `border:3px solid black;`;

    case props.p1 === "red" && props.p2 === 5:
      return `border: 5px solid red;`;

    case props.p1 === "orange" && props.p2 === 15:
      return `border: 15px solid orange;`;

    default:
      return `border:1px solid red;`;
   }
};
```

**Then call it in your styled component:**

```
const SC = styled.div `
  ${mixin}
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
`;
```

And use it as any styled components

```
<SC p1="black" p2={3} />
```

I have created a sandbox. Take a look at the log of the props: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-hill-vyrq9

Comment: I suppose this could also be used with `return css\`...\`` too